# parallel pipelined table function in database

Tags: oracle, function, postgresql, parallel-processing, pipelined-function

I want to ask whether this parallel pipelined table function feature is present in postgres also or not. I am sure , pipelined table function is present in postgres, but whether they exhibit parallelism or not i dont know. Can somebody help me out with this ?

Also , 
Also , i want to ask , HOW parallel pipelined table functions parallelize the query.

Can somebody explain me this step wise , preferably with the help of example.

http://oraganism.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/parallel-enabled-pipelined-plsql-functions-an-old-feature-thats-new-to-me/

Comment: @APC:Thanks for the comments ,i am sorry if i fail to address the issue , i try my best .I am a learner ,can you please explain this where i am going wrong.I have deleted by answer for now.

Comment: This should probably be split into two separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't support parallel processing of one query - so there there are no feature like parallel pipeline functions.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL **9.6+** now (to some extent) [parallelizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55019/can-a-single-postgresql-query-use-multiple-cores/133243#133243) a single query (without much effort from the user). However, since the new feature is still being ironed, how much this benefits your given query, may vary.